# CMake build issue, "C:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe - broken"

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile a relatively simple CMake project in C++, it was working previously on a different computer, but I recently switched and it no longer is able to build.

CMake gives the following output when I try to build:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/Users/huntd/OneDrive - USU/Code/C++/Learning/Post_Transition/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-n97xfq'

    Run Build Command(s): "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E env VERBOSE=1 C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_8b983/fast
    mingw32-make.exe: *** INTERNAL: readdir: Invalid argument
    .  Stop.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have deleted and reinstalled both MinGW and CMake, and I keep running into the same issue. I've looked around for similar errors and I simply don't understand what's going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My advice is to remove your old version of MinGW and use msys2 to install the latest version: [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation)

Comment: Also building on a cloud drive and having spaces in your path could both cause you problems: `'C:/Users/huntd/OneDrive - USU/Code/C++/Learning/Post_Transition/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-n97xfq'`

Comment: @drescherjm Ah, that would make sense, but I used the same filepath on my previous laptop and encountered no errors, I'll try both suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Since you're compiling with mingw, but there's no mingw prefix in the compiler path, this usually means you forgot to add your toolchain file to your initial `cmake` command.

Comment: Same error message - `mingw32-make.exe: *** INTERNAL: readdir: Invalid argument` - has been discussed e.g. in [that thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/thread/8361yl962o.fsf@gnu.org/). As far as I understand, the reason was that because of `PATH` setting MinGW incorrectly takes some dlls from MSYS installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the fix that worked for me for those in the future, installing Msys and installing MinGW through Msys worked and I no longer have the problem.